# Diagonalizable matrix with Characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a diagonal matrix whose characteristic polynomial is 
$P(x)=(x-15)(x-14)^2(x-13)^3...(x-2)^{14}(x-1)^{15}.$
Let $V$ be the set of all $120 \times  120 $ matrices commuting with $A$. What is the  dimension of $V$??

---

Now eigenvalues of $A$ are $1,2,...,15 $. Now from here how decide the dimension of $V$??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assume without loss of generality that$$A=\begin{pmatrix}15 &0&0&0&0&0&\ldots\\0&14&0&0&0&0&\ldots\\0&0&14&0&0&0&\ldots\\0&0&0&13&0&0&\ldots\\0&0&0&0&13&0&\ldots\\0&0&0&0&0&13&\ldots\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots\end{pmatrix}.$$Which matrices commute with this one? Those of the form$$\begin{pmatrix}B_{15}&0&0&\ldots&0\\0&B_{14}&0&\ldots&0\\0&0&B_{13}&\ldots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&0&\ldots&B_1\end{pmatrix}$$where $B_{15}$ is a $1\times1$ matrix, $B_{14}$ is a $2\times2$ matrix and so on. Therefore,\begin{align}\dim V&=\sum_{k=1}^{15}k^2\\&=1\,240.\end{align}